# Is is possible to chain Maybe in case of null/undefined?

Tags: ramda.js, ramda-fantasy

There is a given function, that is fixed and must not be changed:

```
const validate = v => v === "fred" ? "Y" : undefined
```

Now, because I would like to be functional and would like to avoid null-checks I've decided to use `Maybe` (`ramda-fantasy`) for validation function:

```
const vv = val => Maybe(val).map(v=> validate(v)).getOrElse("N")
```

`vv` should return `Y` if it's called with `"fred"` otherwise  `N`.

- `vv(null)` returns `N` -> OK
- `vv("fred")` returns `Y` -> OK
- `vv("ding")` returns `undefined` -> wrong, expected `N`

The problem is, that `Maybe.map` always returns `Just`, that I do not understand (because I'm just learning it). For me I would be beneficial if this function would behave in similar way to `Maybe(val)` that returns `None` or `Just`.

I have two question:

1. Why `Maybe.map` does not handle null/undefined?
2. How to rewrite `vv` that it would return expected values in all three cases?

EDIT: I would like to explain why validate should not be changed: it's just simple example of function coming from external library. I wanted to see how easy/hard is to integrate such libraries into functional programming. So is not about string operations, just about streaming values when at some point it evaluates to null.

EDIT2:

This solves my problem:

```
Either.ofNullable = Either.prototype.ofNullable = function (value) {
    return value == null ? Either.Left("is null") : Either.Right(value);
};
```

EDIT3:
I've implemented my own Either with missing functionality: https://github.com/maciejmiklas/functional-ts/blob/main/src/either.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: Ramda Fantasy is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy#project-status).  The team recommends that you use other implementations of these concepts.

---

But we can still answer this question, as it's likely to be true of any reasonable `Maybe` implementation

Basically, that's not how Maybe is designed to work.  The idea is that you can have a Just holding *absolutely any* value.  That includes the values `null` and `undefined`.

Ramda added a convenience constructor, `Maybe (val)`, which turns into `Just (val)` if val is not a nil value, and into `Nothing ()` if it is.  But that doesn't mean that you cannot create a `Just (null)`.  The main construction technique is to use the static `Maybe .of`.  And you can note that

```js
Maybe (null)    //=> Nothing ()
Maybe.of (null) //=> Just (null)
```

So we're probably not going to make that technique work.  We couldn't just `map` such an existing `validate` over our `Maybe` and expect it to work.  We could, however, work with a version like this:

```js
const validate = v => v === "fred" ? Just ("Y") : Nothing ()
```

Here, we still have one problem.  `Maybe ('fred') .map (validate)` yields `Just (Just ('Y'))`.  We have extra nesting.  But this is exactly what `chain` is for.  It removes such an additional level, so that `Maybe ('fred') .chain (validate)` yields `Just ('Y')`.  We can then use it [like this](https://runkit.com/crosseye/so-64392058):

```js
const validate = v => v === "fred" ? Just ("Y") : Nothing ()
const vv = val => Maybe (val) .chain (validate) .getOrElse ('N')

console .log ([
  vv (null),   // 'N'
  vv ('fred'), // 'Y' 
  vv ('ding')  // 'N'
])
```

Comment: OP did ask to keep `validate` in tact. Does `val => Maybe(validate(val)).getOrElse("N")` work? Nice primer on Maybe.

Comment: @Thankyou: While yes that would work, there seems no reason to use `Maybe` for that.  Simply `(v, r = validate2(v)) => r == 'Y' ? 'Y' : 'N'` would be fine.  Wrapping something in a Maybe only to unwrap it in the same expression doesn't add anything useful.  I suppose I should have also suggested something like `(val) => Maybe(val).map(validate).getOrElse('N') || 'N'` but I assumed that was obvious, and doesn't really help one learn about `Maybe`.

Comment: @Thankyou: Or I suppose we could get even stranger and use something like `(val) => Maybe(Maybe(val).map(validate).getOrElse('N')).getOrElse('N')`.  But I wouldn't be happy with that.

Comment: My original understanding was that `validate` was an imported function and the OP wanted to bring it into the `Maybe` domain

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, I get that, but I was assuming that the goal was to use it somehow together with `Maybe(val)`.  Simply introducing a `Maybe` in the context of a `String -> String` function makes little sense to me; there are plenty of ways to do that better.  But I don't think there's a *good* way to do what I think the OP wants, which is to combine `Just(String) | Nothing()` with `String -> String | Undefined` to get `String ('Y'|'N')`.  The `undefined` (perhaps unfortunately) is a value in the language, and can be contained in a `Just`.  But it's possible that I misunderstand entirely.